# Error when submitting a sitemap through Google Webmaster Tools

Tags: sitemap

I keep getting an "Unsupported File Format" error when I submit a sitemap to Google Webmaster Tools.  I always use hwww.xml-sitemaps.com to create my sitemaps and I've never had an issue before, so I have no idea how to fix this.  Your advice is appreciated!

Here's the specific error I'm getting from Webmaster Tools :

XML Parsing Error: junk after document element
Location: http://www.joshgoodman.com/sitemap.xml
Line Number 3, Column 1:http://www.joshgoodman.com/main.phpweekly0.85

Here is the beginning and end code of my sitemap:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset
      xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9
            http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">
<!-- created with Free Online Sitemap Generator www.xml-sitemaps.com -->

<url>
  <loc>http://www.joshgoodman.com/</loc>
  <changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
</url>
<url>
  <loc>http://www.joshgoodman.com/main.php</loc>
  <changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
</url>
<url>
  <loc>http://www.joshgoodman.com/blog/</loc>
  <changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
</url>
<url>
  <loc>http://www.joshgoodman.com/faqs.html</loc>
  <lastmod>2014-05-20T01:13:17+00:00</lastmod>
  <changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
</url>
<url>
  <loc>http://www.joshgoodman.com/il-cielo-wedding.html</loc>
  <lastmod>2014-05-20T01:13:19+00:00</lastmod>
  <changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
</url>
<url>
  <loc>http://www.joshgoodman.com/inland-empire-wedding-photographer.html</loc>
  <lastmod>2014-05-20T01:13:19+00:00</lastmod>
  <changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
</url>
<url>
  <loc>http://www.joshgoodman.com/palm-springs-wedding-photographer.html</loc>
  <lastmod>2014-05-20T01:13:28+00:00</lastmod>
  <changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
</url>
<url>
  <loc>http://www.joshgoodman.com/blog/niko-and-joshuas-sls-hotel-wedding/</loc>
  <changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
</url>
<url>
  <loc>http://www.joshgoodman.com/blog/ashley-and-walters-four-seasons-il-cielo-wedding/</loc>
  <changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
</url>
<url>
  <loc>http://www.joshgoodman.com/blog/four-seasons-beverly-hills-wedding-emilia-and-anthony/</loc>
  <changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
</url>
<url>
  <loc>http://www.joshgoodman.com/oviatt-penthouse-wedding.html</loc>
  <lastmod>2014-05-20T01:13:28+00:00</lastmod>
  <changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
</url>
<url>
  <loc>http://www.joshgoodman.com/blog/get-out-and-vote/</loc>
  <changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
</url>
<url>
  <loc>http://www.joshgoodman.com/blog/?s=powershot&amp;searchsubmit=Search</loc>
  <changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
</url>
</urlset>
```

Comment: Try to find the '_weekly0.85_' text in your sitemap. It looks like can be a possible error.

Answer (score 0):

You've missed a beginning `<urlset>` tag. And the *sitemap.xml* on your website differs from the *XML sitemap* you've specified in your question.

Comment: Wait I'm confused now.  There is no priority assigned to the pages in the sitemap that's currently uploaded.  So why am I getting the error: 
<changefreq>weekly</changefreq><priority>0.85</priority></url>?  It seems like it's referencing a different sitemap than the one currently in my root directory.

Comment: Log in to your GWT account and check the sitemap you've submitted at _Crawl -> Sitemaps_.